# Do the Imperium know of Eldars history?

Tags: warhammer-40k

and if so, do they know to what extent they ruled the galaxy?

I often wonder why Eldar have such an arogance and if the humans know of how long the Eldar have exsisted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they do.

For once every single Eldar coming in contact with humans will gloat about Eldair Glorious Empire and how meaninglessness is the one created by "Mon-keigh"

> Your kind think you are so magnificent, yet even now, at the nadir of our power, we can manipulate you, turn you to our ends, as easily as you might pull a trigger and fire a gun. Our time will come again, Eldrad has promised us. Once more you upstart Mon-keigh [subject spits] shall kneel before our power! This time we will not be so lenient! We will exterminate you, every world, every vessel, every one of you! Eldrad has seen the stars stained red with your blood, and it pleases him!
>   You think us weak, but we will be your doom, children of Earth. ([Last words of a captured Eldar Ranger, subsequently executed](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Eldar_Quotes))

On top of that there are Harlequins, that could be called Eldar ambassadors, that from time to time visit other races words to show their performance, from which the most important is The Fall of Eldar:

> The Harlequin lifestyle is very like the life of a roaming mime or troubadour of the medieval times. They wander the Webway and occasionally appear at Eldar settlements: on a Craftworld, on Commorragh, an Exodite Maiden World, or even a human world in the Imperium of Man. They perform frenetic, acrobatic dances for the spectators there which are called Masques. Their artistic works portray the Fall, the legendary decline that destroyed the Eldar empire, the birth of the Chaos God Slaanesh, and many other tales from the long history and ancient mythology of the Eldar people ([source](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Harlequin))

But as with every other knowledge in the Imperium access to it is VERY limited. In one Gaunts Ghosts stories you meet an Inquisitor that read the story of the Fall only AFTER starting to pursue her career in the Inquisiton.

As for their arrogance: well, they ruled the galaxy for about 60 million years: between the end of War in Heavens (When Necrons defeated the Old Ones and decided to take a nap to let the galaxy restore itself) to the Fall that happened in M31. Their art, culture and even lifespan is so much greater than anything younger races created.

Answer (score 5):

Imperium as a whole :

**NO**

Some select circles that guard their snippets of information jealously :

**YES**

Imperium supresses everything that is deemed dangerous from the ordinary citizens. Whole populations have been mind-scrubbed for knowing or aliens etc. We see this theme over and over throughout the Black Library books.

- Some of the High Lords of Terra will most likely know some of the Eldar history.
- Inquisition or some branches of it will also posses some knowledge of the Eldar, their capabilities, history etc. Books are a bit more vague here, sometimes even contradicting themselves on facts.
- Some Space Marine chapters that are close to the Craftworlds
- All those persons that have visited the [Black Library](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Black_Library_of_Chaos) ( In - Universe ) and lived to tell the tale

Comment: I'm sure the OP isn't asking if every single citizen of the Imperium knows the Eldar's history.

Comment: @Daft I do understand the basics of the English language. I'm just making a clear distinction of witch of the small groups of Imperiums elitist orders might know some parts of the whole.